# Memory Leak: What exactly is happening behind the scene?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, autofac, serilog

I have a application which stops often due to memory leaks.

`ContainerFactory` class

```
public class ContainerFactory: IContainerFactory
{
    public TTypeOfInstance GetInstance<TTypeOfInstance>()
    {
        return _container.Resolve<TTypeOfInstance>();
    }
    public TTypeOfInstance GetLoggerInstance<TTypeOfInstance>()
    {
        using (var lifetimeScope = _container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            return lifetimeScope.Resolve<TTypeOfInstance>();
        }
    }

    public void ScopedInstance<TTypeOfInstance>(Action<TTypeOfInstance> method)
    {
        using (var scopedInstance = _container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            var instance = scopedInstance.Resolve<TTypeOfInstance>();
            method(instance);
        }
    }
  }
```

I am creating instance of my `logger` in constructor as follow and causes `memory leak` and my application **fails** every alternate day

```
    public MyClass(IContainerFactory containerFactory)
    {
        _containerFactory = containerFactory;
        _logger = _containerFactory.GetInstance<ILogger>().ForContext(GetType());
    }
```

There won't be any memory leak if I change my code as follow

```
  logger = containerFactory.GetLoggerInstance<ILogger>().ForContext(GetType());
```

So, what exactly `BeginLifetimeScope` is doing and how it's helping to kill the memory issue?

And, Is it right way to create a instance? Is there any better way?

Here is memory leak

[image]

This is the exception

> Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
>   at Serilog.Events.DictionaryValue..ctor(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1>)
>   at Serilog.Capturing.PropertyValueConverter.TryConvertEnumerable(System.Object, Serilog.Parsing.Destructuring, System.Type, Serilog.Events.LogEventPropertyValue ByRef)`at Serilog.Capturing.PropertyValueConverter.CreatePropertyValue(System.Object, Serilog.Parsing.Destructuring, Int32) 
>   at Serilog.Capturing.MessageTemplateProcessor.CreateProperty(System.String, System.Object, Boolean) 
>   at serilog.Exceptions.Destructurers.ExceptionEnricher.Enrich(Serilog.Events.LogEvent,`Serilog.Core.ILogEventPropertyFactory)

This is how logger is configured

```
    public static IContainerFactory BuildContainer()
    {
        var containerFactory = new ContainerFactory();
        var appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
        var applicationName = appSettings.Get("applicationName");
         builder.RegisterInstance(containerFactory).As<IContainerFactory>();
        builder.Register(c => GetLoggerConfiguration(applicationName).CreateLogger()).As<ILogger>();
    }


    private static LoggerConfiguration GetLoggerConfiguration(string applicationName)
    {
        var config = new LoggerConfiguration();
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Settings.Default.ApplicationInsightsInstrumentationKey))
        {
            config = config.WriteTo.ApplicationInsightsEvents(Settings.Default.ApplicationInsightsInstrumentationKey, LogEventLevel.Error);
        }

        config = config.
            Enrich.WithProperty("ApplicationName", applicationName).
            Enrich.WithExceptionDetails().
            Enrich.WithMachineName().
            Enrich.WithProcessId().
            Enrich.WithThreadId().
            ReadFrom.AppSettings();

        return config;
    }
```

Comment: How is `ILogger` registered? Can you add an `Autofac` tag if this is Autofac.

Comment: Yes, I found it already and it's Serilog and Autofac showing the high memory. serilog is from here:https://serilog.net/

Comment: There is no way to analyze this problem from the code given, and it'll likely take too much code and work for this to work as a Q&A question. You will need to install a memory profiler and run your program under it, then analyze the results.

Comment: i refused to believe you have memory leaks until you define how you ascertained said leaks.

Comment: @TomTom updated memory leak status as picture in question

Comment: @John ILogger registration code updated in question

Comment: Sad to see people voting for closing the question when they unable to guide or help.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen  I have updated question with memory profile outputs. issue is resolved anyway but i want to know the best practices

Comment: I don't know about the cause for the specific memory leaks, but is there a reason why you're creating a new `LoggerConfiguration` every time? I've also not used Serilog, but I'd expect to register the resultant object from `AppSettings()` once, and use that to create instances of `ILogger` every time I need them.

Comment: @John `LoggerConfiguration`  I have done only once during building container.

Comment: Are you saying that the registration example in your question is simplified? Autofac, by default, registers things as `InstancePerDependency()` (i.e. each time it needs to inject one, it creates a new one), and it will evaluate all of the code in the `Register` method to do so.

Comment: @John it was simplified long before posting the question and memory issue arises only when I use the method  `GetLoggerInstance` from `ContainerFactory`. It clearly proves that life time settings is the root cause.

Comment: I suggest you read how to ask a  proper question on SO. One hand you say you have a  memory leak and you need to restart the service, on another you show an access violation error which kills the process. People need to be able to reproduce your specific issue, not try to guess based on personal opinions.

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu  I have updated the question as you suggestion. I have posted this question so that it help all users once we find the root cause.

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu  I have clearly added screenshots, errors and c# code which is causing the issue. hope it not worth for down votes.

Comment: Perhaps you could add an action for the [`.OnRelease`](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/disposal.html) method in Autofac, so that you can see how things are being disposed, and see if it differs between the two methods you're using. I'd be careful about wrapping the lifetime scope in a `using` and using the resultant `ILogger` outside of that, considering you're disposing of the scope it lives in before you use it.

Comment: Thanks for great points @John. I am working on your suggestion and keep you posted.

Comment: How is the logger configured/registered in the container?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen updated registration code in question.